# Can't import pynput.mouse Controller, Button

Tags: python, pynput

I've installed pynput by using these 2 commands in terminal.

```
pip install pynput
```

```
python -m pip install pynput
```

Both work and it seems that the package was installed correctly - checked in the terminal.

but when I run:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/MyApp/whatsapp_bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pynput.mouse
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Le1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Le1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Le1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 70, in backend
    return importlib.import_module('._' + module, package)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Le1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/_darwin.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pynput._util.darwin import (
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Le1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/_util/darwin.py", line 60, in <module>
    OBJC.PyObjCObject_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 386, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fe4f8c899c0, PyObjCObject_New): symbol not found
```

I'm running the latest python version 3.8 and pip 20.1.1
What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling ?

Comment: yes, it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/420
The latest Pyobjc breaks pynput. Downgrading it to 7.3 fixes this issue.

credits: [Error while importing pynput - dlsym(0x7f90f7d0c310, PyObjCObject_New): symbol not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959461/error-while-importing-pynput-dlsym0x7f90f7d0c310-pyobjcobject-new-symbol-n)

Comment: I've installed pyobjc and downgraded it to 7.3 - still doesn't work, I get the same error.